# communication between parent and child through pipe

Tags: c, process, synchronization, pipe, parent-child

I want a program where the parent and child talk each other.
so the output would be:

- p: value
- c: value
- p: word
- c: word

and so on.....

Below there is an example of code where the output makes first talk the parent and after the childs.
How can I correct the code?

```
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
            pid=fork();
            if(pid==-1){
                    perror("fork\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else if(pid==0){
                    srand(time(NULL));
                    int c;
                    read(fd[i][0], &c, 1);
                    printf("c: value: %d\n", c);
                    char word[c];
                    read(fd[i][0],&word, sizeof(word));
                    printf("c: word: %s\n", word);
                    int sum;
                    sum=c*i;
                    write(fd[i][1], &sum, sizeof(int));
                    printf("c: sended %d\n", sum);
                    int flag=0;
                    printf("flag :%d\n", flag);
                    read(fd[i][0], &flag, sizeof(int));
                    printf("c: flag= %d ->exit\n", flag);
                    exit(1);
            }else{
                    int c;
                    c=rand()%100+1;
                    write(fd[i][1], &c, sizeof(int));
                    printf("p: value: %d\n", c);
                    char word[c];
                    write(fd[i][1], &word, sizeof(word));
                    printf("p: word: %s\n", word);
                    int sum;
                    read(fd[i][0], &sum, sizeof(int));
                    printf("p: sum is: %d\n", sum);
                    int flag=1;
                    write(fd[i][1], &flag, sizeof(int));
                    printf("par: flag exit %d\n", flag);
                    wait(NULL);
            }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, you need to seed the random number generator *before* you fork. The `srand` call you make in the child process won't affect the parent process when it calls `rand`. Secondly you should *always* check what `read` and `write` returns. Thirdly, you read only *one* byte into `c`, but `c` is a multi-byte type (`int` is typically four bytes). That means the majority of bits in `c` will be *indeterminate* (look at them as garbage). It also means that three of the bytes written by the parent process will not be read in that first `read` call, but rather later for the wrong data.

Comment: I've corrected these mistakes but doesn't change anything. The output makes first "talk" the parent and then the child, so they don't exchange any informations.

Comment: Remember that pipes are *one way only*. If you need to both send and receive you need *two* pipes.

Comment: I have a 2-d array for this reason, value 0->read, 1->write

Comment: No that's not right, index `0` and `1` are part of the same pipe. You need *two separate pipes*, created by two distinct calls to `pipe`. Like `int pipes[2][2]; pipe(pipes[0]); pipe(pipes[1]);` Then the parent can use e.g. `pipes[0][0]` to read and `pipes[1][1]` to write, while the child uses `pipes[1][0]` and `pipes[0][1]`.

Comment: What can happen now is that the child does `write(fd[i][1], &sum, sizeof(int))` and depending on scheduling can read it straight back with `read(fd[i][0], &flag, sizeof(int))`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have understood. Could u apply it on a part of the code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To have duplex communication between two processes, you need *two* pipes:

1. One for parent to child communication;
2. And one for child to parent communication

If you use the same pipe for both, then you can end up with a situation like the child writing something to the pipe, and directly read it back again (and the parent will never see the data).

This could for example happen with e.g.

```
write(fd[i][1], &sum, sizeof(int));
// ...
// Could read sum that was written just above in the same process
read(fd[i][0], &flag, sizeof(int));
```

in your child process.

For the example of the `write` and `read` calls shown above, you could have something like:

```
int parent_to_child[2];  // Pipe where parent process write and child reads
int child_to_parent[2];  // Pipe where parent process reads and child writes

pipe(parent_to_child);
pipe(child_to_parent);

// ...

pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    // Other code...

    // Child writes to parent
    write(child_to_parent[1], &sum, sizeof(int));

    // Child reads from parent
    read(parent_to_child[0], &flag, sizeof(int));

    // ...
}
else
{
    // Other code...

    // Parent reads from child
    read(child_to_parent[0], &sum, sizeof(int));

    // Parent writes to child
    write(parent_to_child[1], &flag, sizeof(int));

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much. Now it's much clear!